# How get custome analyzer source from elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, analyzer

I made a `_mapping` request to elasticsearch and see that for one field custom analyzer is used. The output for field like that:

```
"myFieldName": {
  "type": "string",
  "analyzer": "someCustomAnalyzer"
}
```

So is there are a way to get source for that `someCustomAnalyzer`? I have tried request `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=someCustomAnalyzer`
and got:

```
{
   "error": "ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[text is missing]",
   "status": 400
}
```

If I add `text` argument for query string I got analyzing result for analyzing, but I need analyzer definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see it with [settings](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-settings.html). It's more readable now in 1.5 than it used to be.

So if I create an index with a non-trivial analyzer:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "edge_ngram_filter": {
               "type": "edge_ngram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 20
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "edge_ngram_filter"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "_all": {
            "enabled": true,
            "index_analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
         },
         "properties": {
            "first_name": {
               "type": "string",
               "include_in_all": true
            },
            "last_name": {
               "type": "string",
               "include_in_all": true
            },
            "ssn": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed",
               "include_in_all": true
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I can get the index settings with:

```
GET /test_index/_settings
...
{
   "test_index": {
      "settings": {
         "index": {
            "creation_date": "1430394627755",
            "uuid": "78oYlYU9RS6LZ5YFyeaMRQ",
            "analysis": {
               "filter": {
                  "edge_ngram_filter": {
                     "min_gram": "2",
                     "type": "edge_ngram",
                     "max_gram": "20"
                  }
               },
               "analyzer": {
                  "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
                     "type": "custom",
                     "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "edge_ngram_filter"
                     ],
                     "tokenizer": "standard"
                  }
               }
            },
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "number_of_shards": "1",
            "version": {
               "created": "1050099"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/4a38bdb0cb7d381caa29b9ce2c3c154b63cdc1f8